# How do you have to mark up a postal address so it allows invoking an intent on a mobile device?

Tags: html, mobile, semantic-markup

My goal would be that when a mobile user touches an address on a clients website that the appropriate intent would be invoked, allowing the user to, for example, display the location on Google Maps or start a GPS navigation.

Similar behavior is already working great for the phone number. Upon touching it, I'm asked if I want to complete the action using Skype or the Phone app.

So far, I've marked up the address with [hcard microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard) and [LocalBusiness schema.org](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness). I've also added geographic coordinates and marked them up as well. While that's all great for structured data, it didn't seem to have an effect regarding my initial goal.

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?

Comment: cool idea, but appropriate intent is relative...my first though in regards to an address would be to add it to contacts...not arguing or anything, just my two cents

Comment: @albert: Well, yeah. I was hoping that you would get a selection of possible actions. Like "Add to contacts", "Start navigation", ...

Comment: ah context menu. you can create a context menu in html5. the phone feature you mention is html5. actually you should use all html5 input elements because user agents that dont support them just default to what its prior form control was, typically input type text.but back to your question...you could make context menu, and put the link @tacensi answered with as one of your options

Comment: @albert: No, that's not what I'm talking about at all. [This is](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/figs/completeActionUsingBrowsers.png) what I'm talking about. That is not generated by the website, it's an OS feature. I assume a similar feature exists on other mobile devices.

Comment: pretty sure thats a context menu. what is it then? i like the functionality regardless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Apple Maps I used to put a link like the one below. When tapped, it would open the Google Maps App. I don´t have an iPhone to test it right now, but Chrome for Android shows the menu for you to chose which application will handle this type of link (Chrome, Maps, Waze, etc).

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=-22.90132,-43.176527">CCBB (Centro Cultural Banco do Brasil)</a>
```

Comment: Indeed, that works pretty well. Not quite what I was hoping for, but it might be appropriate anyway.

Comment: So, it looks to me like there simply isn't the markup I'm looking for. Using a maps.google.com link like you suggested will cause Android to invoke the intent I was looking for though. And I had no idea that there is no such thing as intents on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I use a geo: URI link, (combined with the arguments that Google Maps likes for after it's pulled up).

```
<a href="geo:37.44462,-122.16326?q=37.44462,-122.16326(CommerceNet)">CommerceNet</a>
```

Support isn't always there yet, but I think it's the closest to a standard that doesn't tie you to one specific app. Works on most mobiles, but didn't work on any desktop last I checked.

For a full solution, I actually combined that with both hCard and Schema.org data to produce a block:

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GovernmentOrganization"
         class="vcard">
    <header>
        <h3 id="contactState"
            itemprop="name"
            class="org fn"
            style="margin-bottom:0;">SD State Capitol</h3>
    </header>
    <a href="geo:44.367064,-100.34588?q=44.367064,-100.34588(State+Capitol)"
       itemprop="address"
       itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"
       class="adr"
       style="font-size:medium !important;color:black !important;">
        <div itemprop="streetAddress"
             class="street-address">
            500 East Capitol Avenue
        </div>
        <div>
            <span itemprop="addressLocality"
                  class="locality">Pierre</span>,
            <span itemprop="addressRegion"
                  class="region">SD</span>
            <span itemprop="postalCode"
                  class="postal-code">57501</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</section>
```